# Akzidenz-Grotesk font in WP

Tags: css

I was looking to change the font on my blog and ran into the suggestions [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/08/the-most-popular-fonts-used-by-designers/).

I am wondering what the right way to specify that the Akzidenz-Grotesk font be used in my blog. For example, I know that to get the Palatino family going, I would need to add the following line to my `style.css`:

```
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
```

What is the equivalent version for this font? I tried

```
body, input, textarea {
    color: #373737;
    font: 15px  "Akzidenz-Grotesk", "Akzidenz-Grotesk", Akzidenz-Grotesk, serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.625;
}
```

which (unsurprisingly) did not work.

Comment: Berthold fonts are not allowed to be used externally in blogs and web pages.

Comment: @Berthold That doesn’t answer the question (that is why I converted it to a comment), and the asker doesn’t even mention a public use.

Answer (score 2):

The name to be used in the `font-family` value is either the full name of the font or the PostScript name. They can be found in the name table of the font as corresponding to `nameID` values 4 or 6. These values can be determined using the DTL OTMaster Light program, provided of course that you have font available in your computer.

However, most computers in the world have no such font. Besides, font names are protected as trade marks only as far as commercial distribution is considered, so there might be free fonts under a name like “Akzident Grotesk” that have no resemblance to the font you have in your mind.

Repeating the same name, or writing it first with and then without quotation marks, does not help. Trying different spellings, like `Akzidenz Grotesk`, might have an impact.

I wonder why you would use `serif` as a fallback for a font that is a sans-serif font even by its name, or why you would use a very large line height for it. Using a font weight like 300 makes sense only if you expect the font family to contain, in the computers of your visitors, a typeface with weight 300, or with some other weight smaller than normal (400).

It might be best if you explained what you expected to achieve by declaring the font.